# SKSpriteNode with UIImage from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to stream images to GPU, and using SKSpriteNode. The images are not in my bundle, and I was wondering if there is some way to work with UIImage instead of imageNamed:

My current idea is

URL -> NSData -> UIImage -> addToFile: -> imageNamed:

Can I add to path and call the image that way, or what would be the best way (is it possible) to reference UIImage by name dynamically when it is not included in bundle?

Comment: try: URL -> NSData -> save file to documents -> imageNamed: - because you really don't want to do that every time your app starts or loads a scene, you **have** to cache the images because there's a lot of people on bandwidth-limited plans (not to mention slow connections).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, apparantly SKTexture can accomodate UIImage, and I ended up something along the lines of

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://superawesomeimage.com.jpg";
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

SKView* theView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:theView];

SKScene* theScene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:theView.frame.size];

SKSpriteNode* theSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:theImage]];
[theScene addChild:theSprite];
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift Answer

```
    let url = NSURL(string: imageURL)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
    let theImage = UIImage(data: data!)
    let Texture = SKTexture(image: theImage!)


    let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: Texture)
    self.addChild(mySprite)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your image. Why do addToFile: -> imageNamed: to get your image? Just do:

```
 NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.somepage.com/yourimage.png"];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL];
 UIImage *yourimage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: I'm trying to reference the image as if it were in bundle. Thanks!